# Export XML from excel using macros for 65000 above rows

Tags: xml, excel, macros, vba

I have an XSD Mapped to Excel containing records over a million. Upon exporting to XML, Not all data is exported.This is a limitation in excel. Is there a macro that can generate records over 65000 rows in excel?

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Have you tried to convert XSD Mapped to csv? I think you can have more lines inside.

Comment: Excel 2010 is the version used. The ouput needed is the XML file exported from excel with an mapped XSD.

Comment: Within you export, are `Integer`s being used? If so, you could change these to `Long` data types

Comment: Below is the simple Map that is used to generate XML file:               Sheets("TESTXML").Select    ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("TESTXML").Export URL:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TESTXML.xml", _

Answer (score 0):

The 65000 rows limit applies to .xls files. Try to save the file as .xlsx (1mln rows limit) or do the calculations in an instance of Microsoft Excel 2007 xlsx and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My Excel file is of .xls extension. Inspite of remapping to the entire table data. The Same amount of data is generated which is limited.

Comment: i think microsoft should work on this to overcome this issue, i have 144,000 lines of data that i prepared mapping but it only export only  13,000 lines